# rename and replace url in all folder with title tag

Tags: php, bash, sed

i need bash script to do this:
replacing the original file name with the title tag of the file ( instead of the space between the words i would like to add  "_".
then replace all links in all folder that contain the original name with the new title name

I start with this :

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in *.html ; do 

mv -v "$f" "$(grep -oP '<title>\K.+?</title>' $f | sed 's#</title>##').html"
mv "$file" `echo $file | tr ' ' '_'` ;  
done
```

but spaces still in place and i didn't figure out how to replace the url in the entire folder with the new title  name
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For doing it also in subfolders, you should work with "find" and a "while loop".

Something like :

```
#!/bin/bash
find . -name "*.html" > listing.txt
while read filepath  
do  
    # Considering the subfolder can have spaces,
    # We will start by separating the filename
    # And dirname
    folderpath=`dirname "$filepath"`
    filename=`basename "$filepath"`  

    # With GNU GREP
    new_name=$(grep -oP '<title>\K.+?</title>' "$filepath" | sed 's#</title>##' | tr ' ' '_')
    # With BSD GREP (for who need the info)
    # new_name=$(grep -o '<title>.*</title>' $filepath | sed -e 's/<title>\(.*\)<\/title>/\1/g' | tr ' ' '_')
    mv -v "$filepath" "$folderpath/`basename $new_name`.html"  
done < listing.txt
```

Comment: i tried to use this script but getting error with grep: grep: .html: No such file or directory mv: /import/smart/.html and /import/smart/.html are the same file-get it in all files and the files name is .html (no name just perfix

Comment: Sure, little typo in the grep, should work with : new_name=$(grep -oP '<title>\K.+?</title>' "$filepath" | sed 's#</title>##' | tr ' ' '_')

Comment: just noticed that few files have "/" in the middle, example: <title>error/blog/denied</title> , <title>error/blog</title> , i would like that those files will be named with the last string as "denied"  & "blog".
how to ignore what before the "/" ?

Comment: you can add a command "basename" at the end of the "new_name" line, should resolve the problem

Comment: Sir - i dont think that this what you ment ? ... new_name=$(grep -oP '<title>\K.+?</title>' "$filepath" | sed 's#</title>##' | tr ' ' '_' | basename ), as it's not working for me.

Comment: Try to be more precise about what you want. Do you want "error/blog/denied" to become "denied", or something else ? The solution I gave you was for that case.

Comment: I want "error/blog/denied" to become "denied", and tried to use your advice as in example ie add in previous commit, but its not working for me. Thank you for your patience

Comment: Then, it should work.  basename "error/blog/denied" gives "denied".  I have updated the complete code, try it.

Comment: tried it and it give output - "basename: missing operand, Try 'basename --help' for more information"/ all file in the main directory were deleted an in sub directory : noo name just the extension

Comment: try to add in the loop `echo $new_name >> /tmp/list_new_name.txt` and check if you have empty lines or that contains only points or symbol

Comment: i added the echo $new_name >> new_name.txt to the loop and this is what it show: the file title is the same as the path structure depth, some of file with extra text after the title path and some not-example:<title>lib/environment/php</title> so it should be php.html or if some text after path like <title>admin/environment/php some text</title> shuld be php_some_text.html

Comment: My bad. `basename` quite simply do not accept input streams, but only parameters.  I've modified the full code. This time, it should work ;-)

Comment: Sorry Sir, now it is changing the files as expected But didn't change the urls in files

Comment: what do you mean with "url in files", do you have an example ?

Comment: all files that were renamed have the old link to theme all over the files body, so no link work as they contain the old name link url. example: let's say we have to files: old_name-1.html (contain link to old_name-2.html) & old_name-2.html (contain link to old_name-1.html) in the body of the files , so if we canging the name of the files we need to do it to the link url. hope this is clear.

Comment: to change the url according to the "new_name" i came up with this addition line to the script: 
sed -i "s/$filename/$new_name/" *.html.  now all url links were changed but just in the current folder and not in subfolders, maybe someone can help fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure why you're using mv twice, try using a variable to store the new filename & doing all your re-writing there.

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in *.html ; do 
  new_name=$(grep -oP '<title>\K.+?</title>' "$f" | sed 's#</title>##' | tr ' ' '_')
  mv -v "$f" "${new_name}.html"  
done
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir , working as expected in the folder but not in subfolders, how it can be run on subfolders as well?

Answer (score 0):

this is my final sulosion to this task:
the script do so:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /some/folder

###############################################################################
## DEFINITIONS                                                               ##
###############################################################################
## Work directory:
DIR=${1}

## Log file to put the files without title:
LOG="log.txt"

###############################################################################
## MAIN                                                                      ##
###############################################################################
for FILE in $(find ${DIR} -name "*.html"); do

    ## Get the string that will be the file new name.
    PATTERN=$(cat ${FILE} |grep -o -P '(?<=<title>).*(?=</title>)')

    ## Some files dont have the <title>some string</title> tag, so dont do any-
    ## thing.
    if [ ! -z "${PATTERN}" ]; then
        ## Get the file directory base and the basename. Both are necessaries
        ## to replace the file indications and rename files.
        BAS_FILE_NAME=$(basename ${FILE})
        DIR_FILE_NAME=$(dirname  ${FILE})

        ## Prepare the string that will be the file new name. Change the space
        ## by the underscore (_).
        STRING=$(basename "${PATTERN}" |tr -s ' ' '_')

        ## Replace all entries:
        for TMP in $(find ${DIR} -name "*.html"); do
           sed -i -e "s/${BAS_FILE_NAME}/${STRING}.html/g" ${TMP} 2> /dev/null
        done

        ## Move the file to new name:
        mv "${FILE}" "${DIR_FILE_NAME}/${STRING}.html"

    else
        ##
        echo "${FILE} : Without <title> tag!" >> ${LOG}
    fi
done
```

hope someone will enjoy it, and it is great to be here, Thank you everybody..